# $I$ is a maximal ideal iff $R/I$ is a division ring

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

> **Theorem.** If $R$ is a commutative ring, then $I$ is a maximal ideal iff $R/I$ is a field

This is a common theorem in books, but this following proof doesn't seem to use commutativity and instead proves that $R/I$ is a division ring. However, I couldn't find any such theorem anywhere. The closest thing I could find is [this](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Maximal_Left_and_Right_Ideal_iff_Quotient_Ring_is_Division_Ring). So I presume it is incorrect, but I cannot figure out where.

Let $R$ be a ring with a maximal ideal $I$.
To show $R/I$ is a division ring, we need to show that for any $a \notin I$,
there is some $b \in R$ such that
\begin{align*}
    (a + I)(b + I) =  (ab + I) = 1 + I\\
    (b + I)(a + I) =  (ba + I) = 1 + I
\end{align*}
Let $J$ be the ideal generated by $I$ and the left principle ideal of $a$,
and similarly $K$ for the right principle ideal.
Since $I$ is maximal, $J = K = R$ and hence they contain $1 \notin I$.
So for some $i_1, i_2 \in I$ and $b,c \in R$
\begin{align*}
    ba + i_1 = 1, && ac + i_2 = 1
\end{align*}
It follows
\begin{align*}
    ba + i_1 + I = ba + I = (b + I)( a + I) = 1 + I\\ 
    ac + i_2 + I = ac + I = (a + I)(c + I) = 1 + I
\end{align*}
So, $a + I$ has both a left and right inverse, and is thus invertible (left and right inverses if they both exist are equal).

Now assume $R/I$ is a division ring. Let $J$ be an ideal that properly includes $I$.
Then there is some $a \in J\mathbin\backslash I$.
Since $a \notin I$, for some $b \in R$
\begin{align*}
    &(b + I)(a + I) = 1 + I\\
    &\implies \exists i \in I \quad ba + i = 1 %(+ 0)
\end{align*}
Hence, $J$ (which includes $\{ ra + i \mid r \in R, \; i \in I \}$) contains $1$.

Comment: The proof is fine. Since $R$ is commutative, the same goes for $R/I$ so $R/I$ is a commutative division ring, that's called a field. Note that since $R$ is commutative, we already have $J=K$ without using the maximality of $I$.

Comment: @Tuvasbien $R$ is not assumed to be commutative in the proof

Comment: What do you mean by "maximal ideal" in the non-commutative setting? I think you must mean maximal two-sided ideal (otherwise you have no guarantee that $R/I$ forms a ring in any useful way).  A maximal two-sided ideal need not be maximal as a left or right ideal. See the examples in the wikipedia page on [maximal ideals](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maximal_ideal) - specifically take $R$ to be the ring of $2\times 2$ matrices over a field, then $0$ is a maximal two-sided ideal, there are many other maximal left and right ideals, and $R/0 \simeq R$ is not a division ring.

Comment: For noncommutative rings, the statement is not true in general if "maximal" means "maximal as a two-sided ideal". The correct statements are that $I$ is maximal as a two-sided ideal if and only if $R/I$ is a simple ring, and $I$ is maximal as a left or right ideal if and only if $R/I$ is a simple left or right $R$-module (or a division ring if $I$ is a two-sided ideal).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The first direction is false. For example, if $F$ is any field (or even division ring) then $\{0\}$ is a maximal two sided ideal in $M_n(F)$. The quotient is clearly not a division ring, unless $n=1$.

Your mistake is assuming that a general element in the ideal $J$ you defined has the form $ba+i_1$. i.e that $J=Ra+I$. If $R$ is commutative then this is indeed the case. But in the noncommutative case this sum might not be an ideal. Remember, an ideal has to be closed by multiplication by elements from the ring from both sides. If we multiply $ba+i_1$ from the right by some $r\in R$, we get $bar+i_1r$, an element which has no reason to be in $Ra+I$.